# java.lang.IllegalStateException while reloading Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, tomcat, illegalstateexception

I'm working on Spring with Hibernate application, It's working fine but while starting or reloading tomcat server, i'm getting `java.lang.IllegalStateException` Exception.

Can anybody explain, why this exception occurring and how to resolve it??

`INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load java.net.BindException. The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact. 
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1600)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createLinkFailureMessageBasedOnHeuristics(SQLError.java:1220)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException.<init>(CommunicationsException.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3270)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.quit(MysqlIO.java:1659)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.realClose(ConnectionImpl.java:4296)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.cleanup(ConnectionImpl.java:1265)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.finalize(ConnectionImpl.java:2667)
    at java.lang.System$2.invokeFinalize(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.runFinalizer(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.access$100(Unknown Source)`

Comment: clean the tomcat  because of  caching older version of the app. and then run the app

Comment: @BaskerAmmu How to Clean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I want to give you couple of choices. You can try it. Any option can fulfill your demand.

1. `Restart your tomcat and apache server` because a long time of using,
   it keeps older version of your application.
2. Clean your tomcat `temp` directory and `restart`
3. **As stated in error**,

> The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for
>   debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which
>   caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.

It may be the real cause that at this moment you are in debugging mode and it doesn't clear the running thread. so remove your break point and run it not debugging

4. If your code contains any kind of thread which are not properly terminated, then this type of error may occur.
   That you have `init()` method but no `destroy()` method, then this type of error may occur. For details, you can follow the link - http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue056.html
5. if the `webapp has stopped, or is stopping`, that means that the `.war` file or `WEB-INF/web.xml` timestamp changed, and the webapp might be reloading. Please check timestamp is OK or not.
6. To turn it off, **set reloadable="false"** in the context definition of
   your app. It might be tomcat's `server.xml`.
   In details solution: 
   The tomcat's server.xml of the reloadable Context is set to false. 
   For example:

```
Context path="/expert" docBase="expert" debug="0" reloadable ="false"/>
```

The solution is easy, as long as the tomcat's server.xml in `reloadable = "true" into false` on the line, but to do so would lose the advantage of hot deployment, and for the development is not very convenient, simply change it or not. This error does not matter.

**Error principle:**

The reason is because the tomcat restart, because the previous tomcat thread has not completely shut down, restart tomcat will report this exception, but this does not affect the normal use, just jump abnormal annoying people. Used hibernate, spring or other large components, when a WEB application system has a lot of class,

if you turned the Tomcat `reloadable = true`, then whenever the relevant documents change, Tomcat stops web app and frees up memory, and then reload web app. it may be a huge project. So we always think if there is only a certain class of overloaded functions, will greatly meet our debugger.

> UPDATE: For code related issue

First, I want to tell you that I have given you some solutions for tomcat basis. Now **I want to give you a solution for code basis**. Would you please cross check your code with this issue? Please follow the URL.

7. http://www.coderanch.com/t/660126/Wiki/Illegal-State-Exception

> UPDATE: For MySQL related issue

8. There are 2 issues.

   - This web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load `java.net.BindException`.
   - This web application instance has been
     stopped already.Could not load `com.mysql.jdbc`.

This is because the **MySQL JDBC driver** on the application under the `WEB-INF/lib` directory, in the re-release of its loaded twice, so long as it can be copied to `%TOMCAT_HOME%/lib` can solve the problem.
We can solve these two anomalies MySQL drivers from the `WEB-INF/lib` folder moved to `%TOMCAT_HOME%/lib`.

9. I suspect this might be happening after the web application is restarted, where it's down for a short period of time. Then some `finalize()` method in the code is probably trying to do some cleanup too late. Whether or not that's in your code or the MySQL driver I can't say. You definitely should only have one version of a jar in a directory at a time. You might want to upgrade it to the [latest](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) (5.1.38 right now) in case something has been fixed that might be affecting you.(Number 9 is copied from @WhiteFang34)

**Related link for 9:** [tomcat 6.0.24 Exception: Could not load com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607672/tomcat-6-0-24-exception-could-not-load-com-mysql-jdbc-sqlerror)

Comment: I already tried 1, 2, 3, 5,, these not working for me.. and im not using any thread in my application.. i also tried 6 but i want to reload my application when changes are made..

Comment: yes it works but some what its like a disadvantage ;(

Comment: @SantoshJadi I agree with you. But if you get better solution, I request you to post your answer, so that we can learn the better option.

Comment: @SantoshJadi Which tomcat version are you using? If older, please use updated version. Sometimes this type of tricky but silly thinks can help you.

Comment: For sure.. Im using Tomcat 7

Comment: @SantoshJadi Would you please check the number 7 link. It may help you.

Comment: @SantoshJadi Would you please check the number 8 for mysql related issue. I hope this can solve your issue. and you can also update mysql connector jar as 9 stated. Please check.

Comment: Number 9 Worked for me.. Thank you Bro

Answer (score 2):

The issue was because of the server cache. Follow the below steps to fix this issue

1. Find the directory called "work" under your tomcat's root directory
2. Delete it completely
3. Restart the server

Issue will be fixed.

Note: In case you have default tomcat installation in linux machine, you have to delete the folder `/var/cache/tomcat7/Catalina`

Comment: @SantoshJadi : Try removing the files under `<tomcat-root>/temp/` also and restart.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the root cause of this problem is that something is leaking JDBC `Connection` objects.

These objects are actually instances of `com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl` ... which is a class with a `finalize()`.  Normally, object finalization tidies up the leaked connections.  In this case, it looks like the sequence of events is as follows:

- the GC runs after the webapp has shutdown
- a ConnectionImpl object is found to be unreachable
- the object's finalize() method attempts to shutdown the MySQL database connection ... which entails sending a message to the server
- when the message send fails for some reason, and the comms-level code tries to create an exception by calling  `com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException`
- that tries to create an exception reflectively ...

The last step is failing because it is trying to use the webapp's classloader for the webapp ... which has been shut down.  Apparently, this is detected by a check that is intended to help programmers diagnose webapps that don't shutdown cleanly.

The best solution is to track down the source of the `Connection` leak(s) and fix it.  If  `Connection` objects did not leak, then they would be closed while the webapp's classloader was still active.

Alternatively, you could simply turn off the check, as described in @Skywalker's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be a simple SQL Error. tThe

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
```

means that an object or class was called on when it was not ready to be called on. These errors at the bottom of the stack

```
at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.runFinalizer(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

look like they come from the [Java Garbage Collector](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html#t2)
attempting to clean up [MySQL Object Pointers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php)
that were temporarily unreferenced during a reboot. It seems to me that your error here is just a few MySQL Object Pointers being halted in the middle of execution when the GC calls their finalize methods and then pauses the application to attempt a clean up the object. (leading to a fail and a throw of this exception)
This error is most likely harmless, and could maybe be fixed by adding a

```
JNI_DestroyJavaVM();
```

to your main thread to be executed on shutdown.

Comment: Quote from Oracle Java Documentation: "Creating the VM
The JNI_CreateJavaVM() function loads and initializes a Java VM and returns a pointer to the JNI interface pointer. The thread that called JNI_CreateJavaVM() is considered to be the main thread" Whenever you use Java you are creating a virtual machine that carries out the tasks you assign to it then terminates.